# How to disable full-screen video playback when the smartphone rotate?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I rotate the smartphone in a horizontal position, then full screen video playback is enabled by default.

I found information that you can change the smartphone settings in the chrome browser settings: chrome://flags/#rotate-to-fullscreen and set the status to disabled.

But is it possible to disable full-screen video playback when smartphone rotated using JS or CSS?

Comment: Listen to [`orientationchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event) event and toggle fullscreen mode.